# How to run 'git gui' on windows7?

Tags: git

I have install Git for Windows from 'http://msysgit.github.com/'
I am running Windows 7.

I checkout android source code using their tool 'repo'. and I use the 'Git Gui' to open the repository. I get this error:

Can you please tell why it is complaining the '.git/config'?

```
fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config
fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config
    while executing
"exec C:/Programs/Git/libexec/git-core/git-config.exe --global --add gui.recentrepo C:/Programs/cygwin/home/mike/Src/android-jb/packages/a..."
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval exec $opt $cmdp $args"
    (procedure "git" line 23)
    invoked from within
"git config --global --add gui.recentrepo $path"
    (procedure "_append_recentrepos" line 16)
    invoked from within
"_append_recentrepos [pwd]"
    (procedure "choose_repository::_do_open2" line 12)
    invoked from within
"choose_repository::_do_open2 ::choose_repository::__o1::__d"
    invoked from within
".buttons.next invoke "
    invoked from within
".buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } "
    invoked from within
".buttons.next instate pressed { .buttons.next state !pressed; .buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } } "
    (command bound to event)
```

Comment: Can you give us the contents of your `.git/config` file? Or, at least, the first couple of lines?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a simple git repository yourself and create few commits. Invoke gitk see if gitk and git-gui works